# problem with question 1 ,week 3 ,Introduction_to_Data_Science_in_Python coursera web site

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Load the energy data from the file Energy Indicators.xls, which is a list of indicators of energy supply and renewable electricity production from the United Nations for the year 2013, and should be put into a DataFrame with the variable name of energy.

Keep in mind that this is an Excel file, and not a comma separated values file. Also, make sure to exclude the footer and header information from the datafile. The first two columns are unneccessary, so you should get rid of them, and you should change the column labels so that the columns are:

['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']

Convert Energy Supply to gigajoules (there are 1,000,000 gigajoules in a petajoule). For all countries which have missing data (e.g. data with "...") make sure this is reflected as np.NaN values.

Rename the following list of countries (for use in later questions):

"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
"United States of America": "United States",
"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
"China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"

There are also several countries with numbers and/or parenthesis in their name. Be sure to remove these,

e.g.

'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)' should be 'Bolivia',

'Switzerland17' should be 'Switzerland'.

Next, load the GDP data from the file world_bank.csv, which is a csv containing countries' GDP from 1960 to 2015 from World Bank. Call this DataFrame GDP.

Make sure to skip the header, and rename the following list of countries:

"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea", 
"Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran",
"Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"

Finally, load the Sciamgo Journal and Country Rank data for Energy Engineering and Power Technology from the file scimagojr-3.xlsx, which ranks countries based on their journal contributions in the aforementioned area. Call this DataFrame ScimEn.

Join the three datasets: GDP, Energy, and ScimEn into a new dataset (using the intersection of country names). Use only the last 10 years (2006-2015) of GDP data and only the top 15 countries by Scimagojr 'Rank' (Rank 1 through 15).

The index of this DataFrame should be the name of the country, and the columns should be ['Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations', 'Citations per document', 'H index', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'].

This function should return a DataFrame with 20 columns and 15 entries.

```
def answer_one():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    energy = pd.read_excel('Energy+Indicators.xls').drop(
        ['Environmental Indicators: Energy'],axis=1).dropna(axis=1,how='all'
                                                           ).dropna(axis=0,how='any')
    for col in energy.columns:
        if col=='Unnamed: 1':
            energy.rename(columns={col:'Country'}, inplace=True)
        if col=='Unnamed: 3':
            energy.rename(columns={col:'Energy Supply'}, inplace=True)
        if col=='Unnamed: 4':
            energy.rename(columns={col:'Energy Supply per Capita'}, inplace=True)
        if col=='Unnamed: 5':
            energy.rename(columns={col:'% Renewable'}, inplace=True)
    energy.replace( '...',np.nan, inplace=True)
    energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply'].apply(lambda x: x*1000000)
    energy.set_index('Country',inplace=True)
    num=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    for idx in energy.index:
        if idx=="Republic of Korea":
             energy.rename(index={idx:"South Korea"}, inplace=True)
        if idx=="United States of America":
             energy.rename(index={idx:"United States"}, inplace=True)
        if idx=="United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland":
             energy.rename(index={idx:"United Kingdom"}, inplace=True)
        if idx=="China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region":
             energy.rename(index={idx:"Hong Kong"}, inplace=True)
        i=0
        for x in idx:
            if idx[i]=='(':
                energy.rename(index={idx:idx[:i-1]}, inplace=True)
            if (idx[i] in num):
                energy.rename(index={idx:idx[:i]}, inplace=True)
            i+=1
    GDP=pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv',index_col=0,skiprows=4)
    for idx in GDP.index:
        if idx=="Korea, Rep.":
            GDP.rename(index={idx:"South Korea"}, inplace=True)
        if idx=="Iran, Islamic Rep.":
            GDP.rename(index={idx:"Iran"}, inplace=True)
        if idx=="Hong Kong SAR, China":
            GDP.rename(index={idx:"Hong Kong"}, inplace=True)
    ScimEn=pd.read_excel('scimagojr-3.xlsx')
    columns_to_keep=[]
    for i in range(10):
        columns_to_keep.append(str(2006+i))
    GDP=GDP[columns_to_keep]
    ScimEn=ScimEn.where(ScimEn['Rank']<16).dropna(axis=0,how='all')
    GDP.rename_axis('Country',inplace=True)
    ScimEn.set_index('Country',inplace=True)
    x=pd.merge(ScimEn,energy, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    y=pd.merge(x,GDP,how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    return y
answer_one()
```

i almost confident that my cod is true but the online corrector say it is false
where did i do mistake?

Comment: Sorry but you need to show more effort in debugging this rather than post the full exercise and a load of code with no explanation of what the errors might be

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a very brief code review:

1. `import` statements should be the first lines of your python file. They certainly should not be inside a function ever.
2. Your function is long, consider breaking it down into smaller functions. For example a function to rename the unamed columns/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html))
3. `energy = energy.rename({'Unnamed 1': 'Country', 'Unnamed 3':, 'Energy Supply'}, axis='columns)` etc
4. pandas are deprecating `inplace`, don't get in a habit of using it
5. `.rename` takes a dict so your loop is unnecessary. You can do it all in one shot e.g.: `rename(index={"United States of America": "United States", "Republic of Korea": "South Korea"}`
6. `num = list(string.digits)`, you'll need to `import string`. But also, I don't know what you're doing with `num` but I'm certain you shouldn't be doing it!
7. `columns_to_keep = GDP.columns.str.contains('2006')`
8. `x`, `y`, `i` etc are not acceptable variable names. Use something meaningful!

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in number of rows you are returning. I have done the same assignment on Coursera and evaluated your code. You should not put `df.rename()` in loop as they work perfectly fine outside the loop. Make sure to write rename these and then merge.

```
energy.rename(index={'United States of America':'United States'},inplace=True)

energy.rename(index={'China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region':'Hong Kong'},inplace=True)

energy.rename(index={'Republic of Korea':'South Korea'},inplace=True)

energy.rename(index={'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland':'United Kingdom'},inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

#Energy

1. Import `pandas` and `numpy` libraries
2. Load Energy dataset
3. Excluding header and footer by dropping rows
4. Dropping rows and columns with entire NaN values
5. Deleting second column and renaming all columns in Energy Dataset
6. Replacing empty values with NaN values
7. Converting petajoules into gigajoules using `lambda` function
8. Correcting all country names and setting country as index of dataset

#GDP

1. Loading GDP dataset
2. Excluding header and footer
3. Renaming column names for our convenience
4. Correcting country names
5. Setting country as index of GDP dataset

#ScimEn

1. Loading ScimEn dataset
2. Getting the rows of rank 1-15
3. Setting country as index of ScimEn dataset

#Joining three datasets

1. Joined using `merge()`
2. Deleting the columns named 'Country Code','Indicator Name', and  'Indicator Code'
3. Setting country as index of entire dataset

At last, you'll be getting dataframe of 15 rows and 20 columns.

```
def answer_one():
        
        # YOUR CODE HERE
        import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
        Energy=pd.read_excel('assets/Energy Indicators.xls')
        Energy=pd.DataFrame(Energy)        
        Energy=Energy.drop(Energy.index[246:]) 
        Energy=Energy.drop(Energy.index[:17])          
        Energy=Energy.dropna(how='all')           
        Energy=Energy.dropna(how='all',axis=1)    
        del Energy['Unnamed: 1']               
        Energy=Energy.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2': 'Country','Unnamed: 3':'Energy Supply','Unnamed: 4':'Energy Supply per Capita','Unnamed: 5':'% Renewable'}) 
        Energy=Energy.replace('...',np.nan)       
        Energy['Energy Supply']=Energy['Energy Supply'].apply(lambda x: x*1000000 )  
        Energy['Country']=Energy['Country'].replace(regex=True,to_replace='[^a-z A-Z]',value='') 
        Energy['Country']=Energy['Country'].replace(['Republic of Korea','United States of America','United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland','China Hong Kong Special Administrative Region','Bolivia Plurinational State of','Falkland Islands Malvinas','Iran Islamic Republic of','China Macao Special Administrative Region','Micronesia Federated States of','Republic of Moldova','Sint Maarten (Dutch part)','State of Palestine','The former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia','Venezuela Bolivarian Republic of','United Republic of Tanzania'],['South Korea','United States','United Kingdom','Hong Kong','Bolivia','Falkland Islands','Iran','Macao','Micronesia','Moldova','Sint Maarten','Palestine','Yugoslav','Venezuela','Tanzania']) 
        Energy=Energy.set_index('Country')
        GDP=pd.read_csv('assets/world_bank.csv')
        GDP=GDP.drop(GDP.index[:4])
        GDP=GDP.drop(GDP.columns[4:50], axis=1) 
        GDP=GDP.rename(columns={'Data Source': 'Country','World Development Indicators':'Country Code',
                            'World Development Indicators':'Country Code',
                            'Unnamed: 2':'Indicator Name',
                            'Unnamed: 3':'Indicator Code',
                            'Unnamed: 50':'2006',
                            'Unnamed: 51':'2007',
                            'Unnamed: 52':'2008',
                            'Unnamed: 53':'2009',
                            'Unnamed: 54':'2010',
                            'Unnamed: 55':'2011',
                            'Unnamed: 56':'2012',
                            'Unnamed: 57':'2013',
                            'Unnamed: 58':'2014',
                            'Unnamed: 59':'2015'})
        GDP['Country']=GDP['Country'].replace(['Korea, Rep.','Iran, Islamic Rep.','Hong Kong SAR, China'],['South Korea','Iran','Hong Kong']) 
        GDP=GDP.set_index('Country')
        ScimEn=pd.read_excel('assets/scimagojr-3.xlsx')
        ScimEn=ScimEn[ScimEn['Rank']<=15]
        ScimEn.set_index('Country')
        join_ScimEn_Energy=pd.merge(ScimEn,Energy, how='inner', on=['Country'])
        Merged_all=pd.merge(join_ScimEn_Energy,GDP, how='inner', on=['Country'])
        del Merged_all['Country Code']
        del Merged_all['Indicator Name']
        del Merged_all['Indicator Code']
        Merged_all=Merged_all.set_index('Country')
        return Merged_all
    
        
        raise NotImplementedError()
```